# Because my test takes a long time to run in? phpunit and laravel

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, phpunit

I have the system loaded in a docker container
I have created a test in the feature folder, the test is simple:

```
public function testExample(){
  $this->assertTrue(false);
}
```

but it takes up to 2, 3 minutes and if I perform a bigger test it takes between 6 and 7 minutes each test. Don't I have it wrong configured? on my docker?
this time it takes 3.8 min

[image]

In this way I run the test

```
docker-compose exec myProject vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/Http/Controllers/testing/TestController
```

Comment: Your tests seem to fail, what are the fail messages?

Comment: oh yes it fails because I am passing a false to `assertTrue()` and even if the result is successful it takes that long

Comment: Yeah that's definitely not supposed to take so long. It is a bit tricky to figure out why it takes so long. What I notice in my projects is that coverage data makes the tests much slower. Are you running with coverage data by default? If your project contains a lot of files then that could be one of the reasons. You can make try running the test outside your docker container to see if that makes it run in a second to know if it's actually a docker problem. Maybe your docker has volumes that are slowing down any tests?